# Error: Could not load database file mysql

Tags: php, mysql, opencart, vps, digital-ocean

I have developed an Opencart website on my Localhost . Now I am going to upload all to Online hosting . I am using digital ocean hosting .I have placed all my files through FTP to /var/www/Html/Home . I have also created database and also configured my config.php files in root and admin folder . But When i open the website It shows a blank page with this error .

Error: Could not load database file mysql!

I cannot Install New version that works but I have my products added and theme menu some edited so cannot install fresh copy . Unable to know Any reason or solution for this error .

My config.php file code

```
<?php 

      error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);

?>

<?php


define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://Mydomain/home');

// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'http://Mydomain/home');

// DIR
define('DIR_APPLICATION', '/var/www/html/home/catalog/');
define('DIR_SYSTEM', '/var/www/html/home/system/');
define('DIR_LANGUAGE', '/var/www/html/home/catalog/language/');
define('DIR_TEMPLATE', '/var/www/html/home/catalog/view/theme/');
define('DIR_CONFIG', '/var/www/html/home/system/config/');
define('DIR_IMAGE', '/var/www/html/home/image/');
define('DIR_CACHE', '/var/www/html/home/system/cache/');
define('DIR_DOWNLOAD', '/var/www/html/home/system/download/');
define('DIR_UPLOAD', '/var/www/html/home/system/upload/');
define('DIR_MODIFICATION', '/var/www/html/home/system/modification/');
define('DIR_LOGS', '/var/www/html/home/system/logs/');

// DB
define('DB_DRIVER', 'mysql');
define('DB_HOSTNAME', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'dbuser');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'dbpass');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'mydbname');
define('DB_PREFIX', 'oc_');



?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't see DIR_DATABASE path. Check if the path is correct.
Check if the file /var/www/html/home/system/database/mysql.php exists (and is accessible by your permissions).

Comment: I have given 755 permission to mysql.php and mysqli.php files , I doubt to include DIR_DATABASE path I also think its necessary but its working on localhost fine

Comment: It's quite possible that the production enviroment has some little difference in configuration. Try to include DIR_DATABASE path also in localhost, if it works well again, try it also on remote, do not trust in non-standard configurations, even if they work well on localhost.

Comment: Thanks Antonio, I have included 
define('DIR_DATABASE', '/var/www/html/home/system/database/');
in config.php but didn't work

Comment: No problem, now it's a challenge! It must works. What version of open cart are you using?

Comment: yes, It was like a challenge . But I was having less time so I choosen to go for new setup on some other server other than Linux VPS that I was using before .

Comment: But there is a new problem with some other website .I prepared that website on locahost then upload all to Linux VPS server . Front part is working fine but when I switch to admin side it shows blank white screen

I decided to take help from stackoverflow . My question is here -
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29191811/blank-page-at-opencart-admin-side