# Blank Page At Opencart Admin Side

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

I have setup opencart store at locahost then i uploaded the all stuff to online hosting and changed paths in config.php file in root opencart folder and Admin folder .

Front is working fine but Admin side not working . It just shows a blank white page.

I debug My Index.php file by placing echo at some places by echo numbers to check it is executing upto that point or not .

I was trying to solve this error . I updated my Files code given here. One change is My Log has recently generated this error -

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function isLogged() on a non-object in /var/www/html/home/catalog/model/catalog/product.php on line 8
```

I am also giving code for my product.php

So It gives error at this line below -
$controller->dispatch($action, new Action('error/not_found'));

I have also included my Index.php file.

My Config.php page in admin folder :-

```
<?php


define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://domain/home/admin/');
define('HTTP_CATALOG', 'http://domain/home/');

// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'http://domain/home/admin/');
define('HTTPS_CATALOG', 'http://domain/home/');
echo '1';

// DIR
define('DIR_APPLICATION', '/var/www/html/home/catalog/');
define('DIR_SYSTEM', '/var/www/html/home/system/');
define('DIR_DATABASE', '/var/www/html/home/system/database/');
define('DIR_LANGUAGE', '/var/www/html/home/admin/language/');
define('DIR_TEMPLATE', '/var/www/html/home/admin/view/template/');
define('DIR_CONFIG', '/var/www/html/home/system/config/');
define('DIR_IMAGE', '/var/www/html/home/image/');
define('DIR_CACHE', '/var/www/html/home/system/cache/');
define('DIR_DOWNLOAD', '/var/www/html/home/download/');
define('DIR_LOGS', '/var/www/html/home/system/logs/');
define('DIR_CATALOG', '/var/www/html/home/catalog/');
echo '2';
// DB
define('DB_DRIVER', 'mysql');
define('DB_HOSTNAME', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'username');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'password');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'databasename');
define('DB_PREFIX', 'oc_');
echo '3';


?>
```

**Index .php Code**

```
<?php 

      error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);

?>

<?php
// Version
define('VERSION', '1.5.6');

// Configuration
if (file_exists('config.php')) {
    require_once('config.php');
}  
echo '4';
// Install
if (!defined('DIR_APPLICATION')) {
    header('Location: ../install/index.php');
    exit;
}

// Startup
require_once(DIR_SYSTEM . 'startup.php');


echo '5';
// Application Classes
require_once(DIR_SYSTEM . 'library/currency.php');
require_once(DIR_SYSTEM . 'library/user.php');
require_once(DIR_SYSTEM . 'library/weight.php');
require_once(DIR_SYSTEM . 'library/length.php');

echo '6';
// Registry
$registry = new Registry();
echo '7';
// Loader
$loader = new Loader($registry);
$registry->set('load', $loader);
echo '7';
// Config
$config = new Config();
$registry->set('config', $config);
echo '8';
// Database
$db = new DB(DB_DRIVER, DB_HOSTNAME, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);
$registry->set('db', $db);
        echo '9';
// Settings
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "setting WHERE store_id = '0'");
 echo '10';
foreach ($query->rows as $setting) {
    if (!$setting['serialized']) {
        $config->set($setting['key'], $setting['value']);
    } else {
        $config->set($setting['key'], unserialize($setting['value']));
    }
}
echo '11';
// Url
$url = new Url(HTTP_SERVER, $config->get('config_secure') ? HTTPS_SERVER : HTTP_SERVER);    
$registry->set('url', $url);
        echo '12';
// Log 
$log = new Log($config->get('config_error_filename'));
$registry->set('log', $log);
echo '13';
function error_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {
    global $log, $config;

    switch ($errno) {
        case E_NOTICE:
        case E_USER_NOTICE:
            $error = 'Notice';
            break;
        case E_WARNING:
        case E_USER_WARNING:
            $error = 'Warning';
            break;
        case E_ERROR:
        case E_USER_ERROR:
            $error = 'Fatal Error';
            break;
        default:
            $error = 'Unknown';
            break;
    }

    if ($config->get('config_error_display')) {
        echo '<b>' . $error . '</b>: ' . $errstr . ' in <b>' . $errfile . '</b> on line <b>' . $errline . '</b>';
    }

    if ($config->get('config_error_log')) {
        $log->write('PHP ' . $error . ':  ' . $errstr . ' in ' . $errfile . ' on line ' . $errline);
    }

    return true;
}
echo '14';
// Error Handler
set_error_handler('error_handler');

// Request
$request = new Request();
$registry->set('request', $request);

// Response
$response = new Response();
$response->addHeader('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$registry->set('response', $response); 

// Cache
$cache = new Cache();
$registry->set('cache', $cache); 

// Session
$session = new Session();
$registry->set('session', $session); 

// Language
$languages = array();

$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "language`"); 

foreach ($query->rows as $result) {
    $languages[$result['code']] = $result;
}

$config->set('config_language_id', $languages[$config->get('config_admin_language')]['language_id']);

// Language 
$language = new Language($languages[$config->get('config_admin_language')]['directory']);
$language->load($languages[$config->get('config_admin_language')]['filename']); 
$registry->set('language', $language);
echo '15';
// Document
$registry->set('document', new Document());         

// Currency
$registry->set('currency', new Currency($registry));        

// Weight
$registry->set('weight', new Weight($registry));

// Length
$registry->set('length', new Length($registry));

// User
$registry->set('user', new User($registry));

//OpenBay Pro
$registry->set('openbay', new Openbay($registry));
$registry->set('play', new Play($registry));
$registry->set('ebay', new Ebay($registry));
$registry->set('amazon', new Amazon($registry));
$registry->set('amazonus', new Amazonus($registry));

// Front Controller
$controller = new Front($registry);
echo '16';
// Login
$controller->addPreAction(new Action('common/home/login'));
echo '17';
// Permission
$controller->addPreAction(new Action('common/home/permission'));
echo '18';
// Router

if (isset($request->get['route'])) {
    $action = new Action($request->get['route']);
} else {
    $action = new Action('common/home');
}
echo '19';

// Dispatch
$controller->dispatch($action, new Action('error/not_found'));

echo '20';
// Output
$response->output();
echo '21';
?>
```

Line 8 to Line 13 In Product.php Where This error come

```
if ($this->customer->isLogged()) {
            $customer_group_id = $this->customer->getCustomerGroupId();
        } else {
            $customer_group_id = $this->config->get('config_customer_group_id');
        }
```

Comment: This White blank screen only appears on Admin side of my opencart website. I have previously used opencart many time . I am using Digital Ocean VPS  Is this thing creating problem I am using it first time and facing this error also first time

Comment: The error you posted pertains to the store front end so not relevant to the blank screen in admin.  Make sure you clear the system/library/cache folder.  If you are using vQmod make sure you clear the vqcache folder.  If the problem persists you'll want to examine apache webserver error logs for answers.

Comment: Also, your make sure your system/library folder is intact and not missing any files.

Comment: In respond to system/library folder I will say Its working fine on localhost but for confirmation i am checking that now and I will also check system/library/cache folder

In response to webserver logs I checked the webserver logs and last error that i got there is already posted in my question here . you can check There is a php error log entry there that i have put in upper portion of my question

Answer (score 2):

For me the issue was lacking a trailing slash for the `DIR_APPLICATION` constant. Make sure all constants use trailing slashes, here is a dynamic setup for `/admin/config.php`:

```
// DIR
define('DIR_APPLICATION', __DIR__ . '/');
define('DIR_SYSTEM', dirname(__DIR__) . '/system/');
define('DIR_LANGUAGE', __DIR__ . '/language/');
define('DIR_TEMPLATE', __DIR__ . '/view/template/');
define('DIR_CONFIG', dirname(__DIR__) . '/system/config/');
define('DIR_IMAGE', dirname(__DIR__) . '/image/');
define('DIR_CACHE', dirname(__DIR__) . '/system/cache/');
define('DIR_DOWNLOAD', dirname(__DIR__) . '/system/download/');
define('DIR_UPLOAD', dirname(__DIR__) . '/system/upload/');
define('DIR_LOGS', dirname(__DIR__) . '/system/logs/');
define('DIR_MODIFICATION', dirname(__DIR__) . '/system/modification/');
define('DIR_CATALOG', dirname(__DIR__) . '/catalog/');
```

Comment: Thanks, I was fighting with the hell of folders after migration. Your example /admin/config.php helped me!

Answer (score 1):

You have create an default customer group for the store, in the setting you have add that group.

Admin `system->setting->option`

Account Section.

Comment: Can you tell what is need for this thing . so that i can know how meaningful it is to do this

Comment: First go to sales menu in the admin panel, will find customer and customer group ,we have to create a default customer group. After that go to settings there you will find an option tab,there in account section add that default customer group then save it.hope it will solves ur problem

Answer (score -1):

Try changing file and folder permissions. php and htaccess files should be 644 folders should be 755.